# python error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python

I am writing this `python` code and I'm getting an error. I've searched through the internet and StackOverflow but nothing works for me!

The error:
    `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list (line 7)`

My code:

```
products = [
    [
        'name',
        'id',
        'number in stock',
        'price ($)'
    ],
    ['iPhone', '1', '100', '999']
]

def instore(item):
    for x in products:
        if products[x][0] == item:
            print(products[x][0] + ': \n id: ' + products[x][1] + ' In Stock: ' + products[x][2])
```

Comment: Line 7 is `],`.

Comment: What you probably want is `if x[0] == item:`

Answer (score 0):

`x` inside the for loop is already the relevant item from `products`. It is not a counter and there is no need to say `products[x]`.

```
for x in products:
   if x[0] == item:
       ...
```

(Also, you probably want to use a dictionary rather than a list here; then you can find `products[item]` directly rather than iterating through the list each time.)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `x` is assigned with each item in the `products` list with the `for` statement, and is not an index, so you should access it as an item in the `products` list:

```
def instore(item):
    for x in products:
        if x[0] == item:
            print(x[0] + ': \n id: ' + x[1] + ' In Stock: ' + x[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other's have already told you about `x` being an element of the list, instead of being a counter variable. If you still want to use a counter, you can do something like,

```
for x in range(len(products)):
   if products[x][0] == item:
       ...
```

The `range(n)` function creates a range (list) from `0 to n-1`. You can read more about range, from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not iterating the index in the list but what you are doing is iterating the element present in the products list in the form of the variable "x" . i think the point will be cleared to you . and checkout the previous answers for the correct code